# Python Def Function not displaying statements properly

Tags: python, function

I am attempting to code in Python (recently getting back into it). I want to use the `def` keyword. But it doesn't seem to work. I am using Python 2.7.5:
The code is

```
def main():
    print "This is a test"
```

And the IDLE console shows it as:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> 
>>>
```

Keep in mind, that if I remove the whole def command completely, the statements will work.
Any insight on this?

Comment: Add `main()` after the function definition to call the function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the function.  See below:

```
>>> def main():
...     print "This is a test"
...
>>> main() #Call the function
This is a test
>>>
```

Comment: The code was properly indented, it was just due to the fact of trying to format the code proerply. And thanks! Completely forgot about calling the function. >_> Guess that;s what happens when you don't care in Python for a few months.

Comment: Ok.  I removed the indentation part of my post.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the main function after that.

Ex.

```
def main():
    print "This is a test."
main()
```

Comment: Thanks! Forgot about calling the function. :/